# Bootstrap navbar collapse box model strangeness

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a Bootstrap collapsable navbar website link below I can't seem to recreate this in fiddle and have inspected the box model values. I'm confused where the white space comes from above the HOME link. There is no padding margin etc.

http://tommaylon.pancakeapps.com/

```
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .nav {
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 0px;
    }   
    .navbar-collapse{
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    .nav > li> a{
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .nav > li:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1){
        padding-top: 0px;
        }

}
```

Comment: giving us a screenshot is useless. we don't know what's what. make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that replicates the behavior or use the F12 inspector to look around until you identify what is causing the issue

Comment: Hi i used the inspector to examine the box model values with no luck.

Comment: Hi i've uploaded site and effect can be observed at screen width <360px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ugh this is much more confusing than it really should be. i hate bootstrap. your problem is that `navbar-nav:{margin-top: 60px}` is being applied to `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`.

correct this with:

```
ul.navbar-nav{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

or whatever appropriate value you want, placed below your declaration for

```
.navbar-nav { ... }
```